# ruby on rails(amistad gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to maintain a friendship within my application for the users to send request and with accept/reject functionalities. I'm using rails 3.2.5 and ruby 1.9.3. I tried the same with amistad gem but unluckily it didn't work. the "include Amistad::FriendshipModel" in amistad is  not including in my User model. I cannot find what is the reason for that. can you suggest me some other gem for this functionality in ruby on rails?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Amistad is [**Amico**](https://github.com/agoragames/amico) - Relationships (e.g. friendships) backed by Redis.

In general a few more gems might also fit your needs: [**ActiveRecord Reputation System** by Twitter](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) or the [**Community Engine**](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine) gem.